# Get the system display color settings

Tags: c, windows

Is there a windows API to get the number of colors currently set on the display settings? What I mean is, if you look at the windows display setting you might get something like:

resolution: 1280x800
colors: 1,000,000

I am using a call to WMI (Win32_VideoController) and get them from there, but I can't use this since the program cannot use WMI.

Is there an API or other way (the registry maybe?) to get the number of colors the system supports?

code is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetDeviceCaps` with the `BITSPIXEL` option is what you're looking for

Comment: great. Now, this will return the information for the main display card, right?
what will happen if there is more than one?

Comment: Then you'll need to pass a different device name to CreateDC().  Use MonitorFromPoint and GetMonitorInfo to get the device name.

Comment: I'm passing as follow: hdc = CreateDCA("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);